# Convert String array to JSON object array using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

Input :

```json
[
  "link1",
  "link2"
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "link": "link1"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2"
  }
]
```

I tried with multiple jolt spec without any luck.
The closest one is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "#link": "[&1].link"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **@** wildcard as looping through the array while assigning the desired key(`link`) on the right hand side such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[&1].link"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]